# Does a free radical localized at one atom in a compound make sense or could it be?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, physical-organic-chemistry

In most of our cases, a dot that represents a radical is always considered affiliated to an atom in a molecule, especially when we talk about a reaction mechanism.

However, Levine's *Quantum Chemistry* [Chap 15.8 - Localized MOs] tells me that

> the Hartree–Fock wave functions of nonclosed-shell electronic states
> are, in most cases, linear combinations of a few Slater determinants
> [for example, see (10.44) and (10.45)], and the above localization
> procedure does not apply to the open-shell orbitals in these wave
> functions. Thus, in a molecule in an excited electronic state with an
> open-shell configuration, the electrons in the incompletely filled MOs
> are delocalized over much of the molecule.

Does that mean a radical is actually delocalized in the whole molecule and that the localized image of a radical is inappropriate? If so, why do we still use it to explain some chemical mechanisms?

Comment: Well, for starters, radicals are rarely excited.

Comment: Is that section of Levine's book specifically about *restricted* Hartree-Fock? In general for open shell systems the RHF solution is *not* a single determinant, and this might be what is being discussed. But we need a little more context

Comment: Is that to say radicals are actually in their ground states but with a high energy? In spite of this, I think the key point is not _excited_ but _open-shell_. Radicals do have open-shell electronic configurations. @Mithoron

Comment: I understand what you said. But it's pointed out that the localized MOs, which the section talks about, do not apply to open-shell systems, which means electrons in these molecules are delocalized. So the question at the top was asked. Do you have any idea? @IanBush